# RSpec Raising an Exception - expected exception, but nothing was raised response?

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec

I am doing a coding challenge and am trying to make one RSpec test pass, however I am unsure why my code is not passing. The error I am getting after running RSpec is:

*1) Plane#land raises an error if already landed
     Failure/Error: expect { plane.land }.to raise_error 'Plane can not land as it is already on the ground'
       expected Exception with "Plane can not land as it is already on the ground" but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/plane_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in '*

the RSpec test code is:

```
describe Plane do

  let(:plane) { Plane.new }

describe '#land' do
    it 'raises an error if already landed' do
      plane.land
      expect { plane.land }.to raise_error 'Plane can not land as it is already on the ground'
    end
  end
```

end

And my main code is:

```
class Plane

  def initialize
    @in_air = true
  end

  def land
    fail "Plane can not land as it is already on the ground" if already_landed?
    @in_air = false
  end
end
```

I have tried substituting back plane for Plane.new and tried using `raise` instead of `fail` and I have double checked, but I can not see why it is not working.

Many thanks

Comment: Where is the definition of already_landed?

Comment: In a private method below which states @in_air = false

Comment: Did you mean `@in_air == false` ?

Comment: ah yes, that it what it should have read, and therein lies the error! Many thanks indeed, you have saved me hours for what was a tiny mistake. I feel dumb now :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined a `already_landed?` method. That means calling `already_landed?` would always raise a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'already_landed?'` exception, but never the expected `Plane can not land...` exception. And therefore your expectation does not pass.

Just add the `already_landed?` method to your model:

```
class Plane
  def initialize
    @in_air = true
  end

  def land
    fail "Plane can not land as it is already on the ground" if already_landed?
    @in_air = false
  end

  def already_landed?
    !@in_air
  end
end
```

Btw: Does it makes sense that a newly created plane will already be `in_air`? I would expect `in_air` to be `false` on initialization and that you need to `start` first. I would change that behavior:

```
class Plane
  attr_accessor :flying

  def fly
    # no exception here, I assume it is save to continue flying, when already in air
    self.flying = true
  end

  def land
    fail 'Plane can not land as it is already on the ground' if landed
    self.flying = false
  end

  def landed
    !flying
  end
end

plane = Plane.new
plane.land
#=> RuntimeError: Plane can not land as it is already on the ground
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but your reasoning is wrong.  If already_landed? is not defined, you get a NoMethodError exception.  It will *not* return nil.